# Dynamically change image content in popover

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4, popover

This is my html

```
<div class="col-12 custom-file" data-toggle="popover-hover">         
    <input type="file" id="fileUpload" class="custom-file-input"  
           accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg">                                 
    <label class="custom-file-label">Choose file</label>             
</div>
```

This is my js

`on page load`

```
$('[data-toggle="popover-hover"]').popover({                                                            
    html: true,                                                                                         
    trigger: 'hover',                                                                                   
    placement: 'bottom',                                                                                
        content: function () {                                                                          
        return '<img style="max-width: 400px; max-height: 400px;" src="' + $(this).data('img') + '" />';
    }                                                                                                   
});
```

This is how I set data for image

```
setFile: function (file) {                                                
    document.querySelector(DOMStrings.fileName).innerHTML = file.name;    

    let fileReader = new FileReader();                                    
    fileReader.addEventListener('load', function () {                     
        console.log(fileReader.result);                                   

        let element = document.querySelector(DOMStrings.customFileHolder);
        if (element.hasAttribute('data-img'))                             
            element.removeAttribute('data-img');                          
        element.setAttribute('data-img', fileReader.result);              
    }, false);                                                            
    if (file) {                                                           
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);                                   
    }                                                                     
}
```

This loads image and shows the selected image in the popover only for the first time, if I change the image in the file upload, it is still showing the first image in the popover, no matter how many times I select another image.

Comment: Is your `setFile` function called when you select a different image?

Comment: yes, every time

Comment: General reminder: the personal pronoun "I" (when referring to yourself) is a capital letter, no exceptions. You have been here long enough to know this. Please make an effort when writing your questions.

Comment: General reminder: you don't need to add to your questions the suggestion that people ask you if they need more information. They know how Stack Overflow works, and we surely do not need usage instructions added to the millions of questions we have here. Please refrain from adding this in the future.

Comment: General reminder: there is no need to add your thanks, regards, appreciations, and so forth. Technical writing is preferred on Stack Overflow, and we remove "fluff" when we find it. Please have mercy on the volunteer editors here - there are not enough of us to go around given the volume of curation that presents itself. It is also all the more arduous if we have to clean up after posters who are flouting the conventions deliberately.

Answer (score 0):

Try using $(this).attr('data-img')

```
   $('[data-toggle="popover-hover"]').popover({                                                      
        html: true,                                                                           
        trigger: 'hover',                                                                                   
        placement: 'bottom',                                                                                
            content: function () {                                                                          
            return '<img style="max-width: 400px; max-height: 400px;" src="' + $(this).attr('data-img') + '" />';
        }                                                                                                   
    });
```

Run the following snipprt

```js
$('input').change(
function(event){
 debugger
  let file=event.target.files[0];
  let src=window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
   $('.custom-file').removeAttr('data-img');
  $('.custom-file').attr('data-img',src);
}
);
                     
$('[data-toggle="popover-hover"]').popover({                                                      
    html: true,                                                                           
    trigger: 'hover',                                                                                   
    placement: 'bottom',                                                                                
        content: function () {                                                                          
        return '<img style="max-width: 400px; max-height: 400px;" src="' + $(this).attr('data-img') + '" />';
    }                                                                                                   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="col-12 custom-file" data-toggle="popover-hover">         
    <input type="file" id="fileUpload" class="custom-file-input"  
           accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg">                                 
    <label class="custom-file-label">Choose file</label>             
</div>
```